# How to disable MyEclipse vairable name suggestions

Tags: java, ide, myeclipse

Every time when I type a variable name, MyEclipse give me name suggestions, and if just press the `SPACE`, it automatically chooses the suggested variable name, which I don't like to use at all. How can I turn off the variable name suggestion? Or can I let MyEclipse to use different short-cut to confirm the suggested word?

[image]

[image: assist setting]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the key binding for content assist in the General > Keys preferences page - look for "Content Assist".

You can turn off the automatic activation of content assist (or change the delay setting) in the Java > Editor > "Content Assist" preferences page - the "Auto Activation" setting.

Comment: Currently I just delay the activation time to 500ms.